# how can I send a dynamic if for redirect_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone help me with redirect_to with a dynamic id

I want to redirect a page with the id from the variable which is set in params

I want

```
format.html { redirect_to '/classrooms/7', notice: 'successfully updated.' }
```

so 7 is my id like classroom/[:id]

I tried to use redirect_to in my controller but din't work

```
@classroom_id = params[:classroom_id]    
@backtoclassroom = "/classrooms/@classroom_id"
```

and

```
format.html { redirect_to @backtoclassroom, notice: 'successfully updated.' }
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this where you would use named url helpers, like `redirect_to classroom_path(@classroom)` , or just `redirect_to @classroom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use the string interpolation? Which you actually tried to use but it didn't work because you are not using `#{}` so your instance variable is not a variable anymore but a literal string. Use something like

```
redirect_to "/classrooms/#{@classroom_id}"
```

Also, make sure you use prepared MySQL statements if you are going to use the user input to query your DB records.